# How can I create a custom InfoWindow layout/background for Google Maps on with a 'stalk'

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I have managed to define and use a custom InfoWindow in my Google Maps app on Android, but I can't figure out how to create a similar custom layout to that shown on the right in [these examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#custom_info_windows) on developer.google.

I have created a simple rounded box with a red outline as a layout and am using this as the background drawable resouce for the layout:

**round_bg_box_white_with_red_border.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#fff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#f00" />
</shape>
```

**custom_info_window.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_bg_box_white_with_red_border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fixed_prefix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="prefix:"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marker_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thsi all works with my code, but I'd like to add the down pointing triangle extension to the background/layout so that the InfoWindow sits a little above the marker and points to it - as in the standard Google InfoWindows.

I want the box itself to be scaled to it the content (hence using a rectangle shape), but the 'stalk' that points down to NOT scale. ie the same behaviour as the standard InfoWindows.

Answer (score 1):

One might consider it as a work-around, but here is my approach to the following design outcome:

[image: layout design sample]

The custom window consists of the content, the outer layout with a drawable as background and an adapted material down arrow icon with 0dp margin.

Your background can easily be updated with yours, despite the fact that a border would not show up. That would need some customization if necessary. The vector code of the triangle might be integrated in another drawable combining the two or smth.

After setup of your infoWindow overwrite

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {
                View infoWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_contents, requireView().findViewById(R.id.map), false);
                TextView title = infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.location_marker_title);
                title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                TextView snippet = infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.location_marker_snippet);
                snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                return infoWindow;
}
```

My layout looks like this (important the 0dp margin bottom, layout may be simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:cropToPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_tooltip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:maxHeight="200dp"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location_marker_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxWidth="230dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/textDark"
                android:textFontWeight="600"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location_marker_snippet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxWidth="230dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/textDark"
                android:textFontWeight="400"
                android:textSize="14sp"

                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_drop_down_24"
        app:tint="@color/backgroundAltDark"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My background is a simple shape with round corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
     <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/backgroundAltDark" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/radius_small" />
            </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And the arrow looks after customized like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="30"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M7,10l5,5 5,-5z"/>
</vector>
```